# Strange behaviour of .item() method of Scripting.Dictionary class in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, key-value

As I have programmed before in Python language I'm accustomed to use the Dictionary structure of data.  Now, I need to program in VBA, and I want to use the same structure, if it is possible.

In order to learn the methods in VBA I've wrote this procedure.  First `.count` method throws "4", but second `.count` method throws "5".  When I've debugged I'm surprised of a new key "COSLADA" is in `dic` with an empty value.  So, when I intent to retrieve an inexistent key item, instead of it throws me an error, the `.item()` method creates a new item with empty value.

```
Sub Diccionarios()
    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With dic
        .Add "ALCORCON", "MADRID"
        .Add "COLLADO VILLALBA", "MADRID"
        .Add "FUENLABRADA", "MADRID"
        .Add "TORRREJON DE ARDOZ", "MADRID"
    End With
    MsgBox dic.Count
    MsgBox dic.Item("COSLADA")
    MsgBox dic.Count
End Sub
```

Is there any other Dictionary method to retrieve a value of item that don't creates an item with empty value when the key don't exists?

Comment: You need to use the `.Exists` method to check for the key first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known behavior and Microsoft regularly gets wrist-slapped in blogs and other online diatribes about it.

The 'workaround' (if you can call it that for a known method of dealing with a known behavior) is to use the Scripting.Dictionary's [Exists method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251562.aspx) to test for the key's existence before requesting the item.

```
Sub Diccionarios()
    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With dic
        .Add "ALCORCON", "MADRID"
        .Add "COLLADO VILLALBA", "MADRID"
        .Add "FUENLABRADA", "MADRID"
        .Add "TORRREJON DE ARDOZ", "MADRID"
    End With
    MsgBox dic.Count
    If dic.Exists("COSLADA") Then _
        MsgBox dic.Item("COSLADA")
    If dic.Exists("FUENLABRADA") Then _
        MsgBox dic.Item("FUENLABRADA")
    MsgBox dic.Count
End Sub
```

Simply put, the backend of the Microsoft Scripting.Dictionary is different from Python's dictionary and they behave differently because *they are not the same thing*. I've never really figured out why so many people cannot grasp that.